# Android SQLiteDatabase as in memory with shared cache

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I try to create an in memory sqlite on Android with shared cache.
The documentation of sqlite [sqlite docu](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) says it is to open with "file::memory:?cache=shared". But when I try it, I'll get an Exception as seen in the stackTrace:

```
E/SQLiteLog( 7004): (14) cannot open file at line 38590 of [d2e6722037]
E/SQLiteLog( 7004): (14) os_unix.c:38590: (2) open(//file::memory:?cache=shared) - 
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7004): Failed to open database 'file::memory:?cache=shared'.
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7004): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database 'file::memory:?cache=shared': Unknown reason; cannot examine filesystem: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.nio.file.FileSystem java.nio.file.Path.getFileSystem()' on a null object reference
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7004):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:252)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7004):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:205)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7004):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:505)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7004):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7004):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:198)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7004):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:918)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7004):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:898)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7004):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:762)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7004):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:751)
```

It seems not to be recognized as in memory, but as real file.

When I try to open a non shared in Memory with path "file::memory:" it is working. But I need a shared one.
What I'm doing wrong? Or does it just not work on Android api?

I tried:

```
 return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(new File("file::memory:?cache=shared"), openParams);
```

and

```
return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                    ":memory:?cache=shared",
                    null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Api Version 30.

Comment: Android SQLite bindings do not appear to export the needed options to open URIs or use shared cache mode.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.OpenParams#getOpenFlags() and compare to https://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html